# Regex in jQuery function that will match ID + any number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

Lets say I have `<div>` object in HTML page that has ID `#videoModal` + any number from **0** to **∞**.

Example of echo output:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='videoModal" . $row['id'] . "' tabindex='-9999' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
    ...
</div>
```

Where `$row['id']` is any number as I said above. Now I have a jQuery function that stops youtube  in Bootstrap 3 modal window that the video is show on.

```
$('#videModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    var src = $(this).find('iframe').attr('src');
    $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', '');
    $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', src);
});
```

But, the above script works only if div tag with ID "videoModal" does not have any number(read `$row['id']`) near it (e.g. #videoModal0, #videoModal1, #videoModal9999). In which way do I match the pattern in run-time that the function will work with every `videoModal+n` ID. (n* - number)

This is what I tried (I tried with other patterns except "." but that brings same result - nothing happens and video still plays after closing the modal window):

```
<script>
    var $videoModalIDn = new RegExp('\\.');
    var $videoModalID = "#videoModal" + $videoModalIDn;

    $($videModalID).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        var src = $(this).find('iframe').attr('src');
        $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', '');
        $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', src);
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

EDIT (here is the fixed code that works):

```
$('div[id^=videoModal]').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    var src = $(this).find('iframe').attr('src');
    $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', '');
    $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: Using regex, does this helps http://jsfiddle.net/xxfebxwL/

Comment: That was the correct logic behind it but I already selected answer by rubiconTwist which does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute selector instead of regex:

The selector would be [id^=videoModal]

Attribute selectors reference :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Ahh thank you, I don't know how I didn't think about that! Cheers.